# How to retain android popup window even if the activity is minimized

Tags: android, popupwindow

I wanted to know if it is possible in Android to retain the popup displayed on top of the activity even if the home button is pressed. 
Example: I have an activity which contains a button. When the button is clicked a popup is displayed and now i press the home button. What I want is activity should close but not the popup :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Dialogs/Pop-ups are attached to activity's window and are relying on activity's life-cycle. So you cant retain/show a dialog once the parent window is away (or in stopped state).

To get this done, you may initiate a new `Activity` with the theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` defined in **AndroidManifest.xml**. This will emulate your activity as a dialog/pop-up window and will contain its own life-cycle.

Comment: Correct.  Additionally, pressing the home button collapses all activities on the stack (not just the current one on top) so even if you start a new activity themed to look like a dialog, it will be minimised if the user presses home

Comment: and if you dont want your dialog themed activity to be resumed after pressing the home button then set `android:noHistory="true"` to your activity tag in manifest too